# flutter json get method return null on calling

Tags: json, get, null, flutter

Hello i am trying to get info from json, 
the code is:

```
GamesList gamesList;


  final String auth = 'Basic'+
  base64Encode(utf8.encode('***:*******'));
 void fetchGames() {
 http.get('000',
 headers: {'authorizationHeader': auth}
  )
  .then((response) {

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  gamesList = GamesList.fromJson(jsonResponse);

} else {
  print("Error");
}
});
}
```

i get this message:

```
I/flutter (27006): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (27006): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#76cf4):
I/flutter (27006): The getter 'games' was called on null.
I/flutter (27006): Receiver: null
I/flutter (27006): Tried calling: games

and this is the stack:

I/flutter (27006): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (27006): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:48:5)
I/flutter (27006): #1      listItem (package:spl/Globals/globals.dart:45:21)
I/flutter (27006): #2      _HomeState.build (package:spl/Pages/home.page.dart:146:13)
I/flutter (27006): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3742:27)
I/flutter (27006): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3654:15)
I/flutter (27006): #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3507:5)
I/flutter (27006): #6      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2255:33)
I/flutter (27006): #7      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:653:20)
I/flutter (27006): #8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208:5)
I/flutter (27006): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter (27006): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter (27006): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:751:7)
I/flutter (27006): #13     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter (27006): #14     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter (27006): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter (27006): (elided one frame from package dart:async)
I/flutter (27006): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 6 of 525 libraries in 788ms.
```

Comment: Take a look at this line: _HomeState.build (package:spl/Pages/home.page.dart:146:13). That is from your stack, so you can probably check that out and might be able to find the issue.

Comment: You might have to add some more code. Gamelist.fromJson and the HomeState

Comment: home.page file is fine the problem it ask information from the get that is not loaded